# how to make transparent alert controller in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
  func clearBackgroundColor(of view: UIView) {
        if let effectsView = view as? UIVisualEffectView {
            effectsView.removeFromSuperview()
            return
        }

        view.backgroundColor = .clear        
        view.subviews.forEach { (subview) in
            clearBackground(of: subview)
        }
    }
```

I have already tried this code and the resulting `AlertController`'s border has removed but the border of buttons inside `AlertController` is still there.

[image: Transparent Alert Controller]

Comment: I could able to understand what you are trying to achieve with this. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Also what is the implementation of `clearBackground `.

Comment: not possible to remove seprator you are in need to create a custom one.

Comment: You can create your custom alert controller and then design it's UI accordingly.

Comment: I'd imagine apple won't take kindly to finding that in a review. You're much safer creating a custom alert.